# How to sort pods based on creation time

Tags: go, kubernetes-pod

I want to sort Kubernetes pod's on creation time. I tried adding logic like this. Here 'result' is array of Pod ( of type k8s.io/api/core/v1/Pod)

```
 sort.Slice(result, func(i, j int) bool { 
    fmt.Printf("%T \n", result[j].CreationTimestamp)
    fmt.Printf("time  %t" , result[i].CreationTimestamp.Before(result[j].CreationTimestamp))
    return result[i].CreationTimestamp.Before(result[j].CreationTimestamp) 
})
```

With above logic , i get error
cannot use t2 (type "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1".Time) as type *"k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1".Time in argument to t1.Before

I tried printing type of "result[j].CreationTimestamp"  which comes to v1.Time. I am not sure what else I am missing. Can anyone please guide me.

Workaround would be to create a another object and set its fields to name and creationTime of Pod and sort it but that would hit performance.

Comment: This may not answer your question, and I don't know where this data is coming from, but can't you let k8s sort it for you? E.g. if you're parsing `kubectl` output, use `kubectl get pods --sort-by=".metadata.creationTImestamp`? That way you won't need to worry about implementing this logic in the first place.

Comment: yes,  from kubectl command i could sort, but i am using golang to interact with  k8. @mkopriva  If I use *,   fmt.Printf("time  %t" , result[i].CreationTimestamp.Before(*result[j].CreationTimestamp)  i get below error " invalid indirect of result[j].ObjectMeta.CreationTimestamp (type "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1".Time)".  result[j] is of type  v1.Pod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1@v0.20.4#Time.Before) `Before` takes a `*Time` therefore I think you have to reference the second timestamp like so:

```
return result[i].CreationTimestamp.Before(&result[j].CreationTimestamp)
```

Comment: Thanks Bäz Kurfer. That works. I need to learn Go lang in deep.